# remove lines with similar keyword if they appear in consecutive lines

Tags: linux, unix

I have got a text file of following format

```
sam has got grade B
score for him is 70
bob has got grade A
score for him is 90 
score for him is 60
ronny has got grade B
score for him is 75
tony has got grade A
score for him is 91
```

As we see line 4 and line 5 both have score and the grade line is missing before line 5.

one way I could think of

grep 'grade' file.txt -A 1

However this would filter only lines where grade is missing. There could be few lines where grade is there but score is missing.

Is there any other better command in unix/linux with which we can remove such consecutive lines which either have two lines containing grade or score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my awk solution,

```
awk '{ if (prev != $2 $3 $4) {print $0} ; prev = $2 $3 $4 ; }' file.txt
```

Note that this solution has a minor bug which is if there are multiple similar lines at the end, it will output one extra line at the end which can be easily removed.

awk by default use spaces to separate words in each line and name them $1, $2, $3, etc for each word in order. `prev = $2 $3 $4;` will save the second + third + fourth word in variable `prev`. if there are consecutive lines in your case, $2, $3, $4 will be the same as those in previous line.  If they are not the same, `print $0` will print the whole line.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked very well. Could you please provide explanation on how it works

Comment: sure. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not Bash command line, but if you want to get rid of two consecutive lines having either both 'grade' or 'score', you can open `vim` and run

```
:%s/^score.*\zs\nscore.*$//
```

To eliminate lines that begin with 'score' following a line that begins with 'score', and

```
:%s/grade.*\zs\n.*grade.*$//
```

To eliminate lines that have 'grade' in them following a line with 'grade in it.